# Excel conditional formatting - find rows that have the same value in two columns

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I want to find duplicates of names (first and last) using conditional formatting. How can I make excel effectively treat the first and las name as one unique value in the formatting so I can see this.

It doesn't need to be using conditional formatting. I'm open to any solutions. Thanks!

Comment: What?  please show some data and expected outcome.  This is very lacking in details.  It is hard to give an answer when we do not know things like in which cells the data resides and whether we are comparing by rows or columns.

Comment: You can create a new column by counting the two columns you want and then use the COUNTIF function to identify the duplicates

Comment: Say first names are col. A, last names are B. In column C, do `=A1&B1` and drag down. Then you can sort by column C. Then "Highlight Duplicates" via conditional formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Without doing a helper column, you can use this Conditional Format:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$100,$A1,$B$1:$B$100,$B1)>1
```

applied to range `=$A$1:$B$100`

(Assuming your first names are in Column A, last Names are in Column B:

[image]